# window.location.href not working, mod rewrite or jquery?

Tags: jquery

I currently have this url in the addressbar

```
http://localhost/cp/subscribed&type=topics
```

When I click `search-button-cp` it should add on `&search=$term`

```
$(".search-button-cp").live("click", function() {
  var url = $(this).parents(".search-container:first").attr("data-url");
  var search =  $(this).parents(".search-container:first").find(".search-input-cp").val();
  window.location.href = url + "&search=" + search;
});
```

instead I get this url

```
http://localhost/cp/localhost/cp/subscribed&type=topics&search=car
```

I `alert(url)` and I get `localhost/cp/subscribed&type=topics` ... so what's the problem?

it should redirect to this url `localhost/cp/subscribed&type=topics&search=car`

How do I solve this?

Here is my mod rewrite incase it is the culprit

```
RewriteRule ^cp/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?(/[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?(/[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?([^.]+)?/?$ /cp.php?o=$1&id=$2&p=$3&query=$4 [L]
```

Comment: When you specify GET arguments, you should put a **?** before the first one, not a **&**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place `http://` before your var `url` in `window.location.href` or make the path relative.

Now your script 'thinks' `localhost/cp/subscribed&type=topics` is an relative path (because there is no `http(s)://`) and your base path, `http://localhost/cp/` is added before the path in the `window.location.href`.

Comment: It's probably enough to make it server-relative, i.e. prepend "/": `window.location.href = "/" + url;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this function instead:

```
function ChangeUrl() {
     var currentUrl = window.location.href;
     var stringToNavigate = "";
     if (currentUrl.indexOf("search") !== -1)
        {
            var stringToReplace = currentUrl.substring(currentUrl.indexOf("search"), currentUrl.length);
            if (stringToReplace.indexOf("&") !== -1)
            {
                stringToReplace = stringToReplace.substring(0, stringToReplace.indexOf("&"));
            }
            stringToNavigate = currentUrl.replace(stringToReplace, "search=" + document.getElementById('yourTextBoxId').value);                  
        }
     else
        {
            stringToNavigate = currentUrl + "&search=" + document.getElementById('yourTextBoxId').value;
        }
     window.location.href = stringToNavigate;
}
```